# Import data into Hive with arbitrary timestamp format

Tags: hive

I have a data file I wish to import into Hive which contains timestamps. The timestamps are of the format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.

I would like to create a table which contains a timestamp type to hold this value, however I can't figure out how to directly import the data.

My workaround is to import the data into a temporary table with my date as a string, then read the data from this temporary table into my permanent table doing the time format conversion on the fly.

So, my entire two-step load function looks something like this:

```
create table tempTable(
timeField string
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";

--load data local here!

create table finalTable(
timeField timestamp
) stored as RCFILE;

insert into table finalTable select 
from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(timeField,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm') )
from tempTable;
```

So finally my question :-)
Is this the 'right' or 'best' way to do it? Am I using an inefficient/stupid workaround?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another work around is change the datetime format of your data file as yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss

Then it will directly cast the data as timestamp datatype to hive table.

Hope this help.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer. The way the original question was written seems to suggest that the timestamp format is fixed ...

Answer (score -1):

create table temptable(
timefield timestamp
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";

This will cast your string 04/05/2014 04:25:55 as timestamp on hive.

Comment: Have you tested this? My understanding is that this would only work with times in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' which is exactly the problem I am having as the data is not in that format to begin with. My experience is that your approach will just lead to NULL values

Comment: @PeterCogan Yes, that is exactly what happens (creation of NULL values) if you do as it says here. Any work around?